# Как использовать два разных упаковщика в двух фреймах одного окна?

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

Есть у меня два фрейма в одном окне (с одинаковым `master`, что нужно сделать, чтобы в первом фрейме использовать `grid()`, а во втором `pack()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте в одном фрейме `grid()`, в другом `pack()`, в чем проблема)

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

Button(frame1, text='Button 1 in Frame 1').pack()
Button(frame1, text='Button 2 in Frame 1').pack()

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack()

Button(frame2, text='Button 3 in Frame 2').grid(row=0, column=0)
Button(frame2, text='Button 4 in Frame 2').grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Первые две кнопки в первом фрейме расположены при помощи метода `pack()`, две другие кнопки во втором фрейме расположены при помощи метода `grid()` (специально расположил по диагонали). Нельзя расположить виджеты внутри одного фрейма разными методами, но внутри разных фреймов ничто не мешает использовать разные методы упаковки.

[image: Скриншот]